# React.js iterate through object keys and values using map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object:

```
var Customers = {
 name = 'John',
 last = 'Doe'
}
```

I have imported to my react component, I'm having difficulty looping through object content.

Here is what I have tried

```
import Customers from './customer';

var customer = Customers.map(function(s){ return s.name });
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined(…)(anonymous
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Also, you can't use map for objects like this. You should write

```
var customer = Object.keys(Customers).map(function(s){ return Customers[s].name });
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of equals `name='John'` it's suppose to be `name : 'John'`.

If you are trying to retrieve the name you could access the variable like `Customers.name`. If you are trying to do something more with it let me know and I am more than happy to help.